# How to change two JTextFileds in real time?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, real-time, jtextfield

I'm trying to make a GUI, which converts Arabic to Roman; or the other way.
I want to output as the user is typing the input in real time!

I'm using `JFrame` for the GUI, and 2 x `JTextField` controls for the Roman / Arabic edit / display.

Answer (score 0):

*here is a solution that dynamicly changes the* textFieldRoman *while typing in* textFieldArabic *and vice versa.*
*Hope that helps.*

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener( new AWTEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void eventDispatched( AWTEvent event ) {
    switch( event.getID() ) {
    case KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED:
      // Your conversions Arabic to Roman depending if textFieldRoman or textFieldArabic has the focus
      // best with actionArabic and actionRoman both of type AbstractAction
      break;
    case FocusEvent.FOCUS_GAINED:
      // if textFieldRoman break; otherwise fallthrough - keeps the focus in one of the textfields
    case WindowEvent.WINDOW_OPENED:
      textFieldArabic.requestFocus();  // start with focused textFieldArabic
      break;
    }
  }
}, AWTEvent.FOCUS_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.WINDOW_EVENT_MASK );
```